# in_array keeps returning false no matter the query

Tags: php

Okay I have a database with 3 ip addresses. and when I run the following code even when the table is empty still runs the same code:

fetch row model:

```
$whitelistip = explode(",", $usercheck->ipwhitelist);
```

and the code to check if the users ip address/addresses is in the row which will be stored with commas like: 123,4323,354. Yet when the database has the same ip or the row is empty the following if code always runs successfully and can't get past it :(

```
        if(isset($whitelistip) && !in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$whitelistip)){

            $date =  date("F Y h:i:s");
            $addlogin = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO logins(email,date,ip,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            $addlogin->execute(array($email,$date,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],'Unsuccessful login'));
           echo '
              <div class="row row-centered">
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Your IP address is not on the whitelist for this account
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>';
```

Comment: what returns `var_dump(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelistip));` and `var_dump($whitelistip);`

Comment: if (!empty($whitelistip) && is_array($whitelistip) && isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) /*strange nginx setup?*/ && !in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $whitelistip, true))

Comment: `!in_array` shouldn't that be `in_array`?

Comment: or this    if(count($whitelistip) > 0 && is_array($whitelistip) && !in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$whitelistip)){
    ..
    }

Comment: I guarantee the first one returns false.  It is also useful to know what $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is. var_dump is your friend.

Comment: carca it returns bool(false)

Comment: returns false aswell. I want the code to check the database to see if the users ip is equal to a whilelisted ip, if it is carry on with the script, or if the whitelist row is empty to carry on with the script as well, yet it returns false all the time

Comment: I'm starting to think that the error now lies in your model.

Comment: If your $whitelistip variable is false then it "is_set".  Also in_array is going to return false if you dont give it a proper array.  True && !False = True. That's why your "Oh snap" message appears.

Comment: I'm confused :( How would I fix it.

Comment: How is this being populated `$usercheck->ipwhitelist`?

Comment: via a row in the users table via this query:

 public function UserCheck($email)
 {
   $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?");
         $sql->execute(array($email));
         return $sql->fetchAll();   
    }

Comment: then I'm populating the      $whitelistip = explode(",", $usercheck->ipwhitelist); like that

Comment: Oh and I'm initiating it like:         $userchecks = $this->model->UserCheck($email);

Comment: Are you using CI or other type of framework? `ipwhitelist` without a `$` is being treated as a constant. So, I couldn't say for sure what's wrong with your code at this point.

Comment: Yeah, i'm using a framework, so the -> is actually working because I've echoed it and it shows the row. I'm asuming it's something to do with the if statement or the explode...